# Create list containing proportionate number of data from n other lists

Tags: python, apache-spark

New to PySpark programming. I have been trying this problem, and want to know if there's a more efficient way to solve it.
I have 15 dataframes, each containing 2 columns: Website name and hits. Each of these dataframes have a different number of records. I want a final dataframe in the end, where I have taken the top records from each dataframe (based on hits) and added them there. The catch is, I am taking a proportionate number of records from each. So for example, if I want 1500 records in the end, and I only have 2 dataframes of size 10,000 and 5000 each, I will take 1000 from the first and 500 from the second.

So currently, I have an implementation like this:
1. Call count() on each dataframe. Now I have the length of each so I can determine how many records I want from each dataframe.
2. Call orderBy() on each dataframe, based on hits. Then call limit() on the ordered data frame so I can limit it to the total number of records I need per dataframe.

The above implementation works, but it's pretty slow. This also sounds like a very greedy approach, so would appreciate any hint to make this better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're approach seems correct although you still have to iterate through a list of dataframe. We can try this approach to parallelize the computations:

First let's create sample dataframes of varying lengths:

```py
import random
length_list = [10, 15, 20, 30]
df_list = []
for l in length_list:
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        sc.parallelize([[chr(ord("a") + i), random.randint(0, 100), l] for i in range(l)]), 
        ["name", "hits", "df_name"]
    )
    df_list.append(df)
```

Note that I created a column called containing the length of the dataframe as its name.

We'll create a `union` of all the dataframes to only have one work table:

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_list)
```

Now we'll compute the `percent_rank` within each `df_name` group using a `Window`

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("df_name").orderBy(psf.desc("hits"))
df = df.withColumn("pct_rn", psf.percent_rank().over(w))
```

You can now filter the dataframe to which ever proportion of each group you want, say `1/3` for instance

```py
res = df.filter(df.pct_rn < 1/3.)
```

Finally to check the final lengths are 1/3 of the original ones:

```py
res.groupBy("df_name").count().sort("df_name").show()

+-------+-----+
|df_name|count|
+-------+-----+
|     10|    3|
|     15|    6|
|     20|    7|
|     30|   10|
+-------+-----+
```